# Find files (but ignore them in certain folders)

Tags: python

I want to find files of a specific type in a certain directory. The directory has lots and lots of subfolders and I want to ignore certain ones. I am using the following code-

```
def locate(pattern, root=os.curdir):
    '''Locate all files matching supplied filename pattern in and below
    supplied root directory.'''
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(root)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            yield os.path.join(path, filename)


for filename in locate("*.s2p"):
          #do something
```

I think there should be some way to change os.curdir to os.curdir (minus some folders) , or perhaps I can check current path and put in a conditional loop ? I tried os.cwd() but i got an error message saying 'module' object has no attribute 'cwd'

Comment: thanks ! Dunno how i missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore some subdirectories while walking with `os.walk`, you can mutate the value of "dirs". E.g.

```
ignored = ["foo", "bar"]
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(root)):
    for dir in ignored:
        if dir in dirs: dirs.remove(dir)
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        yield os.path.join(path, filename)
```

This would skip all subdirectories named "foo" or "bar" while walking the directory tree.